# Java fraction calculator, global variables?

Tags: java, eclipse, calculator

This is my second time asking this question because this assignment is due tomorrow, and I am still unclear how to progress in my code! I am in an AP Computer programming class so I am a complete beginner at this.  My goal (so far) is to multiply two fractions.  Is there any way to use a variable inside a particular method outside of that method in another method? I hope that wasn't confusing, thank you!!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class javatest3 {
    static int num1 = 0;
    static int num2 = 0;
    static int denom1 = 0;
    static int denom2 = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("Enter an expression (or \"quit\"): "); //prompts user for input
    intro();

}
public static void intro(){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
    String user= input.nextLine();
    while (!user.equals("quit") & input.hasNextLine()){ //processes code when user     input does not equal quit
    StringTokenizer chunks = new StringTokenizer(user, " "); //parses by white space
    String fraction1 = chunks.nextToken(); //first fraction
    String operand = chunks.nextToken(); //operator 
    String fraction2 = chunks.nextToken(); //second fraction
    System.out.println("Fraction 1: " + fraction1); 
    System.out.println("Operation: " + operand); 
    System.out.println("Fraction 2: " + fraction2); 
    System.out.println("Enter an expression (or \"quit\"): "); //prompts user for more input


while (user.contains("*")){
    parse(fraction1);
    parse(fraction2);
    System.out.println("hi");
    int num = num1 * num2;
    int denom = denom1 * denom2;
    System.out.println(num + "/" + denom);
    user = input.next();

        }
    }
}

public static void parse(String fraction) {
    if (fraction.contains("_")){
        StringTokenizer mixed = new StringTokenizer(fraction, "_");
        int wholeNumber = Integer.parseInt(mixed.nextToken());
        System.out.println(wholeNumber);
        String frac = mixed.nextToken();
        System.out.println(frac);
        StringTokenizer parseFraction = new StringTokenizer(frac, "/"); //parses by forward slash
        int num = Integer.parseInt(parseFraction.nextToken());  
        System.out.println(num);
        int denom = Integer.parseInt(parseFraction.nextToken());
        System.out.println(denom);




}
else if (!fraction.contains("_") && fraction.contains("/")){
    StringTokenizer parseFraction = new StringTokenizer(fraction, "/"); //parses by forward slash
    int num = Integer.parseInt(parseFraction.nextToken());  
    System.out.println(num);
    int denom = Integer.parseInt(parseFraction.nextToken());
    System.out.println(denom);



}else{ 
    StringTokenizer whiteSpace = new StringTokenizer(fraction, " "); 
    int num = Integer.parseInt(whiteSpace.nextToken());  
    System.out.println(num);
}
}}
```

Comment: You're asking the wrong question. You're answer to the specific question `Is there any way to use a variable inside a particular method outside of that method in another method?` will always be no. The variable is encapsulated as a local variable.

Comment: You can declare the variables as global. Or you can pass the variables as parameters.

Comment: If this is the same question you asked here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20207131/java-fraction-calculator then you should delete this question

Comment: Why don't you explain how you want your program to function and what is not working about it.

Comment: I want to multiply two fractions together inside the intro method inside the while loop. Inside the while loop I call the parse method for each fraction. I want to use the numerator and denominator variables from my parsed fractions in the while loop, which is in a different method. I hope that cleared some things up! Sorry for being confusing!

Answer (score 4):

> Is there any way to use a variable inside a particular method outside of that method in another method?

Yes you can do that. You can declare a variable in a method, use it there and pass it to another method, where you might want to use it. Something like this

```
void test1() {
    int var = 1;
    System.out.println(var); // using it
    test2(var); // calling other method and passing the value of var
}

void test2(int passedVarValue) {
    System.out.println(passedVarValue); // using the passed value of the variable
    // other stuffs
}
```